# Obtain displayed order of Excel worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to find the position of a worksheet as it is displayed in a workbook.

For example, assume I have a workbook starting with Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3 in that order. Then a user drags Sheet2 to left, before Sheet1.

I want Sheet2 to return 1, Sheet1 to return 2 (and Sheet3 still to return 3).

I can't find a way to determine this in VBA.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Index
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836415.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I had incorrectly assumed that the index was the creation order not the displayed order!

Answer (score 4):

You can just iterate the `Worksheets` collection of the `Workbook` object. You can test yourself by running the following code, switch the order around in the UI, then run it again:

```
Option Explicit

Sub IterateSheetsByOrder()

    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    For intCounter = 1 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        Debug.Print wb.Worksheets(intCounter).Name
    Next intCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: Ha! Thanks! Actually, I'm know how to iterate through worksheets but for some reason thought the order of the Worksheets collection was based on the creation order, not the displayed order. I've held this misconception for a lonnnng time. And Tim William's reference "proves" that it is indeed the displayed order.

Comment: @HEdgePig Tim's answer works, as long as you don't anticipate that the user might *change the sheet names*, then, all bets are off. While both of these are good/reasonable answers, I'd caution that it's generally not safe to rely on either the sheet names, nor their index, unless you have absolute control over the structure of the workbook (i.e., it is protected structure).  If you really need VBA to operate on a specific sheet, you need user input & validation to test it :)

Answer (score 1):

To loop through all worksheets in a workbook use `For Each WS in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` where `WS` is a worksheet object. Hence to obtain order of Excel worksheets as shown, we may also use the following code:

```
Sub LoopThroughWorksheets()
Dim WS As Worksheet

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print WS.Name
    Next

End Sub
```

To obtain an output like `Worksheets("Sheet1").Index` then you may use this code

```
Sub IndexWorksheet()
Dim WS As Worksheet, n As Long

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        n = n + 1
        If WS.Name = "Sheet1" Then Debug.Print n
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: **Note:** The Worksheet collection refers to all worksheets in a workbook. It does not include sheets of type chart meanwhile the Sheet collection refers to all sheets belonging to a workbook including sheets of type chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sheets object. In your example, reading `Sheets(2).Name` should return `Sheet1`.

Answer (score 0):

Right answer provided by Anastasiya-Romanova, but missing some important details.

There are two methods of doing this. First, with a `For Each` loop:

```
Sub ListSheetNames()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print ws.Name
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Second, with a basic `For` loop:

```
Sub ListSheetNames
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Name
    Next i
End Sub
```

You will find the second method will always output the names in the sheet *index* order, which is generally the order the sheets were created in unless you change the index. Simply rearranging the sheets from the workbook window *won't* change the index.

Therefore, the first method is the correct way to do this. It will always follow the tab order as you see on your screen.

Answer (score 0):

Below code works even if sheet is renamed or its sequence is changed.

```
Sub Display_Sheet_Tab_Number()

        Dim WorksheetName As String
        Dim n As Integer

        WorksheetName = Sheet1.Name
        MsgBox Worksheetname
        n = Sheets(WorksheetName).Index     'n is index number of the sheet
        MsgBox "Index No. = " & n

End Sub
```

Comment: As a rule I'd prefer the `Worksheets` collection to `Sheets` if referencing worksheets as the latter collection generally can contain shapes, too. (In your case, however this shouldn't matter as you are referencing the worksheet's *Code(Name)* within the project).